# Как сделать статистику из даты в бд

Tags: python, mysql, sql, telebot

Есть статистика вот в таком формате(на скрине показал скрин из бд)
Как или какой запрос нужен что бы запросить колличество users_id за последний день,неделю,месяц и тд?
[image: .]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(u.user_id) FROM (SELECT user_id FROM some_table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(data, '%y%v') = date_format(DATE(NOW()), '%y%v') GROUP BY user_id) u;

# Неделя в формате год (две последние цифры года), неделя (с ведущим нулем)
SELECT user_id FROM some_table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(data, '%y%v') = 1908; # 8-я неделя 2019 года

# За прошлую неделю в формате год (две последние цифры года), неделя (с ведущим нулем)
SELECT user_id FROM some_table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(data, '%y%v') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW()), '%y%v') - 1;

# Год в своем привычном формате
SELECT user_id FROM some_table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(data, '%Y') = 2019;
```

Ну и дальше в таком-же духе

Comment: а vin после select это что?и вместо egistration_date нужно data(имя столбца где хранится дата)?

Comment: @АртёмПетров Это название поля, просто по живой базе запросы писал. registration_date кстати тоже навание поля

Comment: @АртёмПетров, переделал под ваши данные, только название таблицы не забудте поменять

Comment: Так вы написали же как получить конкретную дату.А как получить колличество users_id за последнюю неделю,день,месяц?В таблице с каждый users_id записывается дата(Человек написал /start,в бд записался его id и дата когда он нажал)

Comment: @АртёмПетров вставил в начало

Comment: а этот запрос за какой промежуток времени вычисляет?

Comment: @АртёмПетров, если вы про верхний то за текущую неделю. + исправил, чтобы искал только уникальные id

Comment: Почему то в консоли sql отображает правильно,2,а в самом боте None.Сейчас прикреплю скриншоты себе в ответ....

Comment: @АртёмПетров а диалект какой? В ответе MySQL

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108132/discussion-between---and-wairua).